# A simple linq query to start the day

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a class that contains a ints, string and pointers to other classes. I'm trying to extract the strings and perform a substring operation on them before I select.Distinct. My LINQ code looks right

```
List<string> crops = (from m in cropTypes
            let cw = m.CropName
            let kw = cw.Substring(0, cw.LastIndexOf(")") + 1)
                select(kw).Distinct()).ToList();
```

I have also tried

```
var crop = …
List<string> crops = crop.ToList();
```

When I attempt to compile, I'm getting

Cannot implicitly convert type

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>> to System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>
```

on the ToList() line.

m.CropName is definitely a string

Why does the compiler think that I'm using a char list rather than a string list and how do I fix this.

Nothing like a simple problem to stump you at the start of a day!

Comment: try this IEnumerable<string> crops =.... and remove .ToList();

Comment: Because you are performing operation on string object. `let cw=m.CropName` Here `CropName` is of type of string and not `IEnumerable<string>`. so if you perform `Distinct' on string then it will return you `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: Try this lambda expression. `cropTypes.Select(c => c.CropName.Substring(0, c.CropName.LastIndexOf(")") + 1)).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: Please have a look through [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) and edit to allow people scanning a question list to actually know what your question is about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
List<string> crops = (from m in cropTypes
  let cw = m.CropName
  let kw = cw.Substring(0, cw.LastIndexOf(")") + 1)
  select kw).Distinct().ToList();
```

If you call Distinct on a string, you're actually enumerating the string's characters.